# Move semantics on individual vector elements

Tags: c++, vector, move-semantics

What is the behavior of a `std::move` on an individual vector element?
e.g. (grossly simplified code follows)

Will this do the proper move and do I need to `erase()` the moved element?

I normally use a copy constructor and a delete, will the compiler optimize for a move (synthesized) instead of using a copy constructor in some cases?

I tried using smart-pointer wrappers and didn't see a significant speedup.
Move semantics look like what I want to use.

```
template< class T >
class Foo
{
};

vector< Foo< T > > v1, v2;

v2.emplace_back( std::move( v1[ 2 ] );
```

I don't see significant speedup using move operations and I think I've implemented the move constructor and move assignment operator correctly.

Please shed some light on this problem.

Comment: "*I don't see significant speedup*" - it's quite a meaningless statement without providing what was your test case, what is your hardware, what is your compiler and what are your compilation settings, i.e. compiler flags. You *can* move an element from vector. If you move a standard library object, it will end up being in *valid, but unspecified state*, which enables you to perform only actions which require no preconditions on it (you can pretty much only erase it or assign to it in most cases).

Comment: `class Foo` has no data members so there is no difference between a move and a copy.

Comment: Present a real [MCVE]. Move semantics are irrelevant in the code you showed us.

Comment: This question strikes me as oddly specific. Why do you think a vector element would be different than any other named variable with regards to `std::move`?

Comment: The Foo class contains no data members.  There is nothing to move.  The performance will be the same as when there is nothing to copy.

Comment: Please ignore the fact I have no move operations in Foo

Answer (score 0):

Move semantics have two jobs:

- Indicate that ownership of a resource (such as some allocated memory, or a FILE* pointer, or a stream) changed hands
- Avoid unnecessary copies in the above cases.

For example, let's say we have a vector:

```
vector<int> a; 
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { 
    a.push_back(i); 
}
```

If I write:

```
vector<int> b = a;
```

This makes a copy of every single element in `a`, so it's a slow operation. However, if I write

```
vector<int> b = std::move(a);
```

None of the elements in `a` are copied, and this ends up being a lot faster. However, `a` no longer owns those elements. We can demonstrate it using the below code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using std::vector;

    vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
    vector<int> b = std::move(a); 
    if(a.data() == nullptr) // This should be true now
        std::cout << "a.data() is null now\n"; 
    if(a.size() == 0)
        std::cout << "a.size() is zero now\n"; 
}
```

On my system, using gcc and clang, this code prints

```
a.data() is null now
a.size() is zero now
```

This applies even if you have a wrapper class:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Wrapper {
   public:
    // Because all the members of Wrapper are public,
    // the compiler automatically generates move and copy constructors
    T value; 
};


int main() {
    using std::vector;

    Wrapper<vector<int>> a = {{1, 2, 3}};
    Wrapper<vector<int>> b = std::move(a); 
    // Same output as before
    if(a.value.data() == nullptr)
        std::cout << "a.data() is null now\n"; 
    if(a.value.size() == 0)
        std::cout << "a.size() is zero now\n"; 
}
```